# optimize multiple show hide div functionality in a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to optimize my code. Actually I have multiple show/hide div functionality in a single web page. currently I am doing bad approach by making multiple function for each div.

So I want to know a good approach so that only writing a single function I can achieve the functionality.

Only by using jquery

P.S: Not by **angular.js**

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: function showProp() {
    $(".allow_res_div").toggle(1000);
    $(".limit_count_div").hide(1000);
}
function showLimitProp() {
    $(".limit_count_div").toggle(1000);
    $(".allow_res_div").hide(1000);
}
function uploadDiv() {
    $(".csv_upload").show(1000);
}
function preset() {
    console.log("preset called !")
    if ($("#preset").is(':checked')) {
        $(".csv_upload").hide(1000);
    }
}
function itemList(){
    $("#itemList").toggle(2000);
}